# Is my irrelevant field of work experience a negative when applying for higher studies?

Tags: masters, application, germany

I am currently working in TCS as an Oracle analyst. I did my bachelor's of engineering in Mechanical Engineering in 2017. Now I want to pursue my Master's in the same field. I am planning to apply to universities in Germany. Will my two years of working experience in IT sector affect my admission?

Answer (score 1):

If you are applying to schools in Germany, your work experience is largely irrelevant whether or not it is in the discipline you want to study at the master's level. This is because the prerequisites for master's study at German universities is generally an equivalent bachelor's degree at the undergraduate level. However, if your bachelor's degree was not completed at a German university, you will have to petition to have your degree recognized as "equivalent" before being allowed to enroll.

There are some exceptions for "international" programs and special master's programs that do not require a specific degree program but their requirements and procedures must be investigated on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Do I need to present a Letter of recommendation from my work manager if the irrelevant work experience doesn't count for admission process?

Comment: You only need to provide documents the university explicitly requires for admission. If they didn’t ask for it don’t include it.

Answer (score 1):

I oversee admissions for more than 30 Master's programmes through the Graduate School I manage. In general, your work experience cannot hurt, and may help, your application to most Master's degrees at my UK university. The only exception is the handful of programmes that are classified as "professional" programmes. For example, we offer a type of Master of Business Administration that requires at least five years of experience in a relevant professional capacity and our Master of Public Health and MA TESOL requires similar experience.

In the typical (non-professional) programme, programme directors actually prefer students with some work experience (not necessarily related to the area of study).

You should differentiate between your job title or company on the one hand and your responsibilities on the other. You might be working for a steel production company but your responsibilities aren't in the area of mechanical engineering. Likewise, you might be working at an IT firm but you might be involved in managing the power generation of the building. You need to be clear how about your experience.

In the end, your experience cannot be changed. It is, in fact, worse for you to obscure it just because it doesn't fit the field you wish to enter. Employment, even misemployment, still produces life skills that are relevant in the broad sense.

Good luck!